# how to return error_array(); in codeigniter 2.2.1

Tags: php, codeigniter

trying to return form_validation as an array using `_error_array();` by extending the library with  the following code in `my_form_validation.php`

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function error_array() {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }

}
```

however i get a call to undefined function n      `error_array();`
in my controller i have       `$this->form_validation->error_array();`
i have tried renaming the      `my_form_validation.php` with    `MY_Form_validation.php`
but nothing seems to be working dont know if its done diffrently in codeigniter 2.2.1 compared to other posts on here

Comment: About my and MY - look what is set in config.php

Comment: yeah my config is still set to default MY_ but even when changing file name to MY_Form_validation.php it still returns call to undefined function error_array

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124323/extend-form-validation/30126133#30126133 the same question

Answer (score 0):

'Nothing seems to be working' doesn't help if there is no explanation what is going on on your screen/in yoour application. 
Regardless, you have to include constructor in your newly created library that calls parent code.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function error_array()
    {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }

}
```

Also, you would load that library without prefix:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

or similarly in `autoload.php` app config file.

More about [Extending Native Libraries](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html).

Comment: Are you sure that you need a contructor when extend system library?

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::error_array() in /home/scotiadesignco/public_html/tfsv/application/controllers/user.php on line 41

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::error_array()  on line 41

using the class   class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function error_array()
    {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }

}

and from the controller
$run = $this->form_validation->run();
        if ($run == false) {
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()]));
        }

Comment: Please copy that code in your update of question. @splash58, constructor is not mandatory, but that way he would have ability to use code from parent constructor and there is getting existing CI object by reference.

Comment: @Tpojka if i understand you right, you say that parent constructor will not be execute if no one in extending class. It seems to be wrong. His code should work without a constructor. At least in ci 3.

Comment: I misunderstood meaning of use constructor in child class. Luckily, I'd say in safe way. :) And yes, in CI3 there is function already for this what is wanted here. Just checked both system files 2.2.0 and 3.0

Comment: @Tpojka ok :) I put above link to the same question. Maybe it will help